# How to make a sidebar that stretches to the page length?

Tags: html, css, layout

If I set a `min-height: 700px;` on my sidebar, it works fine, however if the content length goes beyond 700 px, then the sidebar ends and the page content takes up the full width of the page. I want the sidebar to go down the length of the page, as long or short as the content is. How can this be done?

Here's my sidebar's css code:

```
#sidebar
{
    float: right;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width: 25%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Changing the height to `100%` causes the sidebar to disappear completely.

Here's the html code;

```
<bod>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content">Content here....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a `position:absolute;` with `bottom:0px;`

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/McJG8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div id="content">Content here....</div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:700px;
}
#sidebar
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100px;
}
```

The `#parentDiv` now have `min-height:700px;` if its stretched by its contents, the `#sidebar` will stretch as well.

Comment: does not work if i add more content. Try copying and pasting `content here <br />` about 100 times in the content div

Comment: @ClickUpvote You have given the `#parentDiv` a **fixed** `height`, of course the contents will not force it to stretch, use `min-height` instead. Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/BxBRd/

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the exact requirements of what you're trying to do, this sounds like a solution that could easily be fixed using [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).